# Is there a standard way to update a feed that uses a mysql database?

Tags: php, ios, mysql, xcode, feed

I have an iOS app where people can join topics and post content and everything is stored in a mysql database. When they've joined a topic, there's a feed of posts (like iMessage or WhatsApp) that needs to be updated as soon as there's a new post.

The only way I know to do this is to set a timer and check every second to see if there's a new post. This seems like it may overload the server if my app gets big and there's tons of users all requesting data from the server every single second. Is there a more efficient or standard way of keeping a feed up to date or is this what regular apps are doing? Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to poll the network. That's very hard on the user's data usage as well as on your system.

Instead, you want to push out notifications to the users when they have new messages.

You probably don't want to use Apple's Push Notification service for this because the user can disable push notifications for your app, and [Apple says this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2265/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010376-CH1-TNTAG23):

> If you are sending multiple notifications to the same device or
>   computer within a short period of time, the push service will send
>   only the last one.

Instead, consider using a third party push service that doesn't have these limitations, or create your own. Basically, make a TCP connection to the server from the client and wait, or send notifications from the server to the client via UDP.

Typically, you don't send the actual data in the push notification. Instead, you just tell the client to retrieve the data from the server.

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on my application (which is a self-study project) and in the end went for the following solution:

The checks should have the least overhead as possible. I've noticed Twitter's checks are not authenticated. You can actually check for any Twitter user if there's new content waiting for them. Why not, it can do no harm.

So I created a folder (for myself): /_/changed/jflamman. inside that folder there are several folders for each running session (multiple devices means different sessions and different results when checking).

.htaccess checks if the username is an existing dir, if the session is valid and then responds with the index.html of the current session:

```
RewriteEngine On

#apply only to /_/changed/<username>/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/_/changed/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ [NC]

#get session id to check against current session only
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} (PHPSESSID=)([^;]+) [NC]

#make sure folder /_/changed/<username>/<PHPSESSID>/ exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}%2/ -d

#rewrite to /_/changed/<username>/<PHPSESSID>/index.html
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ /_/changed/$1/%2/index.html [L]
```

This either returns a '+' (yes, there is new activity), a '-' (no new activity) or an 'x' (user/session doesn't exist - some script kiddo trying to hack perhaps?);

NOTE: DO NOT COPY/PASTE ABOVE SNIPPET FOR REAL LIFE PUBLIC SITES - it contains a major security risk. The PHPSESSID must be validated with a regex. If someone would change the PHPSESSID cookie for, say '../../../etc/passwd', depending on your server's settings this could turn into a disaster. This is work in progress..

On the client side, a simple ajax call checks every 10 secs (it doesn't do anything else yet)

```
function servercall() { 
    $.ajax({ 
        url: '/_/changed/jflamman/',
        success: function(data) { 
            console.log(data);
            setTimeout(servercall, 10000);
        }
    }); 
}
```

Response time: 12ms. My own name to be replaced with the current user :-P (@todo: above example will fail when there's no server response or any other type of error - page will render dead until refreshed)

On the server side, new posts are stored in the database as well as in the file system. I'm using symlinks for that. Each user has a folder. Each post gets stored as an individual json file. If user 1 & user 2 become friends, user 1 gets a symlink to user 2's folder and vice-versa. That way they can access each other's posts without the need to copy them and when a user edits an existing post all peers see the updated version immediately.

I'm still experimenting what goes faster: database queries or traversing the file system. But I assume that when the application gets more complicated, concatenating some pre-formatted json files will be faster than a database query full of joins, looping through the result sets, etc.

When someone I follow or who is my friend, posts a new comment or update, or edits an existing one, at the time of posting it checks which users are symlinked. It updates all these users' session folders' index.html to "+".

That will trigger the `servercall()` function to initiate another function which finds out what's new.

I store the last checked time in a temp file:

```
touch --date "2015-02-15 18:46:59" /tmp/u.1.s
```

(@todo: the session is not incorporated yet - the 's' will become the session id) And when we want to check what's new, we use the previously saved timestamp to look for any json files that are new or modified (edited perhaps, changed suffix from -published to -deleted). Something like (this one's off the top of my head, it may not work - forgot to save it):

```
find /some/path/to/jflamman -mindepth=1 -maxdepth=2 -type f -newer /tmp/u.1.s
```

will return the files that are modified since the last check (including the symlink'ed files!). I use "cat" to concatenate individual posts to a valid json response object. This example returns all my personal posts sorted by date (each json object is stored in the file system with a trailing comma - the filename starts with a timestamp) and creates a 'cached' version of my personal timeline:

```
echo '{"status": [' > ~/domains/some/public/folder/jflamman.json && find . .* -type f -exec cat {} + | sort -u | sed 's/^\(.*\),$/\1/'>> ~/domains/some/public/folder/jflamman.json && echo ']}' >> ~/domains/some/public/folder/jflamman.json
```

I'm just storing it in a public folder for now to see the output. In real life this would not be stored in a public folder.

Of course when this all fails, a fresh database query will be the fallback.

My main point / summary: my application makes use of 3rd party libraries and middleware. For example Bolt as CMS, Apigility as API and Laravel for additional functionality. All these have their overhead. Even though I love Bolt, Apigility & Laravel I try to minimize the use of them. If something can be achieved without involving PHP, 3rd party libraries and using Linux & Apache native functionality instead, I think that adds to the overall flexibility of the application.

Comment: Very interesting and informative. Thank you. The downside to the socket route is keeping track of ip's on the server as well as the whole thing being much more complicated than the ajax route. However, it would use less cell data for the user and be easier on the server, if I understand correctly. On the other hand, the ajax type requests could be really small and negligible and if Twitter uses that method, I'm thinking it might be the way to go. The best choice isn't clear to me unfortunately.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how the cached JSON object would/might/should be stored? It wouldn't be stored in the database, right? Would each account have a separate file containing the object?